# 403 Forbidden when trying to call Microsoft Bing Speech API from a bot

Tags: speech-recognition, botframework, bing, azure-cognitive-services

Update: the code works perfectly with the trial key from Microsoft (f2da0a19f4d94875880e9fbaceabc97d), but fails with my own key that I generated in Azure. Whaat?

Solution: I used a key for "Translator Speech API" instead of "Bing Speech API". That was the mistake. Wow. Two hours wasted.

---

I am writing a bot that take speech input. For that, I am using Microsoft's Bing Speech API.

I am sending a request as follows and get a 403 Forbidden error. According to the official docs, 403 means authentication or quota problem. However, I have a paid account (not a free one) and the authentication token seems to be received correctly.

URL:

> https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=ulm&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=en-US&device.os=bot&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=45d58c78-e2d8-444f-83c8-9a5dca7225ba&requestid=a3613a79-d84b-497d-87d7-19b19552c0a5

Headers:

> Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJlV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZGV2Lm1pY3Jvc29mdHRyYW5zbGF0b3IuY29tLyIsInN1YnNjcmlwdGlvbi1pZCI6ImM4ZWQyMTNlNjUyMTRhYzc4MDFlNGU0M2RjZmQ1ZWZkIiwicHJvZHVjdC1pZCI6IlNwZWVjaFRyYW5zbGF0b3IuUzEiLCJjb2duaXRpdmUtc2VydmljZXMtZW5kcG9pbnQiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5jb2duaXRpdmUubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS9pbnRlcm5hbC92MS4wLyIsImF6dXJlLXJlc291cmNlLWlkIjoiL3N1YnNjcmlwdGlvbnMvZmU4ZjI4ZDktZDJlNy00YWY0LxIwOGUtNWU3N2Y5YTc0ODY2L3Jlc291cmNlR3JvdXBzL2JvdHMvcHJvdmlkZXJzL01pY3Jvc29mdC5Db2duaXRpdmVTZXJ2aWNlcy...bWljcm9zb2Z0dHJhbnNsYXRvciIsImV4cCI6MTQ5MTQwNTcxM30.mdFdi98OGyjZ_sDYvd2lMWZqvPMROYyiChQz0JKh7fk}

The response I get is 403 Forbidden without any additional info.

Any ideas? I'm just using Microsoft's reference implementation from here - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText - but with my own subscription key.

Code:

```
    public async Task<string> GetTextFromAudioAsync(Stream audiostream)
    {
        var requestUri = @"https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=ulm&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=en-US&device.os=bot&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=45d58c78-e2d8-444f-83c8-9a5dca7225ba&requestid=" + Guid.NewGuid();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var token = Authentication.Instance.GetAccessToken();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            //using (var binaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(StreamToBytes(audiostream)))
            using (var binaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME").ToString() + "\\site\\wwwroot\\test.wav")))
            {
                binaryContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("content-type", "audio/wav; codec=\"audio/pcm\"; samplerate=8000");

                var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, binaryContent);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                try
                {
                    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Server responded: " + response.StatusCode);
                    }
                    return data.header.name;
                }
                catch (JsonReaderException ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(responseString, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have found your answer, please post it as an answer and accept it as such.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a key for "Translator Speech API" instead of "Bing Speech API". That was the mistake. Wow. Two hours wasted.